# Can Blackbery app use BIS(Blackberry Internet Service),when it is not registered in Blackberry App store

Tags: blackberry

I developed a Blackberry app,it is working with WIFI. According to the [documentation](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Different-ways-to-make-an-HTTP-or-socket-connection/ta-p/445879), an app gets access to BIS only if it is approved from their app store. Is there any other way to test the app on a Blackberry device when it is not connected through Wi-Fi, but through mobile internet?

> BlackBerry Internet Service:
>   Applications are also able to make connections through the BlackBerry Internet Service. This connection route is available to third-party developers and is subject to an application approval process

Answer (score 3):

I don't know where you got this from:

`an app gets access to BIS only if it is approved from their app store`

But it's not true.

An app only gets BIS access if you apply for it and receive approval from RIM. The easiest way to do this is apply for [BlackBerry Push Services](https://developer.blackberry.com/services/push/). It usually takes a few days.

You can still test your app on a mobile data connection, you just can't use BIS (which is the most reliable way of establishing a connection).

Comment: im sorry i did not get you. So this means an app can work on BIS connection?

Comment: Any app can work with a BIS connection, you just need to get approval from RIM.

Comment: How do we get approval from RIM?Does it require any kind of certified approval?Can you please provide me some link that explains this?

Comment: @ Dontuner - Thank's for u reply. Is there any other option to test my app with BIS(with out getting the approval from RIM). Can you please provide me some link's for registering my App.

Comment: You cannot test a BIS connection from your app without having approval from RIM. Just register for Push (link in answer) and you'll get access real quick.

Comment: @ Dontuner - I attented Mobile Technology Summit,2012 in India.I met some guy's from BlackBerry,they told that we can use BIS when our app get's approval from RIM.You provided me a link right,for that also i need the RIM Application number,which i can get only when my App is approved from RIM

Comment: @Nitesh "for that also i need the RIM Application number" - No, you don't. Check out the Push application form: https://www.blackberry.com/profile/?eventId=8121 there is nothing which requests an application number.

Comment: @ Dontuner - Sorry i have seen the down link in the first link that you have provided me. Can you give me your mail id, i am having some doubts.

Comment: @Dontuner - Can i do push notification for the app which is developed on BB OS 5.0,from the SDK which is provide in https://developer.blackberry.com/services/push/

Comment: Separate questions should be asked in new posts on SO